# Entity Framework Power Tools & PostgreSQL JSON Data Type

Tags: json, entity-framework, postgresql, ef-power-tools

I have been playing around with the PostgreSQL JSON Data Type and when I try to reverse engineer code first with EF Power Tools JSON Data Type is ignored. If one manually configures the JSON filed in the FluentAPI configuration then everything is working. I have been using DevArt PostgreSQL driver, .NET 4.5.1, EF 6.x.

Is there a way to generate the JSON Data Type via EF Power Tools ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to report a bug to the folks who wrote the reverse engineering tool. It should be emitting unknown data types as "String" with a warning, or doing something along those lines, not ignoring them.

Comment: Yup done that https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2031 I hope they solve this soon, otherwise we need to manually add a lot of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will investigate the possibility of adding runtime support for the JSON data type in EF-provider of [dotConnect for PostgreSQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/) and notify you about the result. This should fix the described problem with EF Power Tools.

Comment: The JSON data type is supported in the latest (7.2.100) build of dotConnect for PostgreSQL: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=28936.

Comment: We will try the build and get back to you if we find any issues. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for so late response, I have an issue with the 7.3.115 version I get the following error when I try to include the object that has a json field "UNION types json and character varying cannot be matched", any ideas ?

Comment: Please send us ( http://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html ) a small test project with the corresponding DDL/DML script for reproducing the issue.